# PHP update stdClass object

Tags: php, api, object, stdclass

I am wanting to update a stdClass Object to set a value.

The object:

```
[info] => stdClass Object
    (
        [flags] => Array
            (
            )
```

I want to set the `flags` to this:

```
 [info] => stdClass Object
        (
            [flags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ForceSSL
                )
```

I have tried

```
$response = $services_api->postWithFields("/package/$Package/web/", [
  

  'update' => (object) [
    'info' => [
            'flags'   => 'ForceSSL',
            ]
        ]
    ] );

var_dump( $response );
```

However, this shows a response of `NULL` - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you cast to object, everything is cast to object, including flags.

Comment: @AlexBarker - sorry, not sure what you mean?

Comment: What you have will produce `$obj["update"]->info->flags` which is not what you said you were trying to get to.  I have no idea why response is null without seeing that method and knowing how the service you are calling works.

Comment: Could we convert this to chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222502/room-for-designer-and-alex-barker